# OData Web API Hide/Remove key from Response

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

I want to remove key from sub class but still want to make the sub class query-able and expandable. 
So like User ->Addresses addresses should not have key in response. But still I should be able to apply filter and should be able to expand etc.

Answer (score 0):

If Address type is marked as EntityType, then key/ID is required (Entities are just pointless without a possibility to identify them). If you really want to have a keyless Object, it must be a ComplexType in IEdmModel, so User->Addresses is Composition, not Association.

If you are new to OData, there is a lot to read about EDM concept, [here](https://odata.github.io/WebApi/13-02-ComplexTypeWithNavigationProperty/) you can find an dead simple example of ComplexType with navigation property.